# Trying to get data from 2 tables from mysql to show up in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need assistance in understanding how to work with 2 tables from a database. I tried writing the code like this but it did not work. It works in MySQL but not in php. I am new coder trying to learn, but I am stuck any help would be appreciated. first and last name are on 1 table. Price is on another table.

Also I am getting this error

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

index.php

```
 <?php
    include ('db.php');
    $sql='SELECT * FROM `user_info` ,`customer_order` WHERE user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';

            $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


        if(! $run_query ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
          echo "First Name:{$row['first_name']}  <br> ".
                "Last Name:{$row['last_name']}  <br>".
                "price:{$row['price]}  <br>";

            }
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` isn't compatible with `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: oh did not realize I did that

Comment: also is MySQLI preferred method of writing code

Comment: mysqli is preferred over mysql. The mysql functions have been deprecated for quite a while and actually were removed as of php 7.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake and mixed up MySQL with mysqli I fixed the issue and it is working thanks from Don't panic.

```
<?php
include ('dbconnect.php');
$sql='SELECT * FROM `user_info` ,`customer_order` WHERE user_info.user_id=customer_order.uid';

        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    if(! $run_query ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
   }

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo "name:{$row['first_name']}  <br> ".
            "Last:{$row['last_name']}  <br> ";

        }
```